# How to ensure the concurrent safe access to ballerina package variable

Tags: concurrency, ballerina

How to ensure that variable is thread/concurrency safe in ballerina? There is a lock feature but it says it is experimental? Is there any other proper way(tested/matured) to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lock is the only way to ensure that 2 strands will not try to manipulate the same variable in Ballerina at the moment.